# Silverlight TreeviewItem IsSelected seems not working

Tags: silverlight

I am currently setting the IsSelected of a Treeview item to true from code behind, unfortunately the visual state doesn't change.

We have a style for selected state but it is not triggered when IsSelected is set from code behind.

```
   TreeViewItem item = CurrentTree.Items.Where(i => (Guid)(i as TreeViewItem).DataContext == objectId).FirstOrDefault() as TreeViewItem;

              if (item != null) {

                   item.IsSelected = true;

                    CurrentTree.UpdateLayout();

                    OnTreeSelection(null, null);

                }
```

Comment: You should post some code then it'll be easier to help.

Comment: The same problem occurs if U deselect item this way. It seems deselected, but clicing on it doesn't select it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue before, and I realized that you must make sure you set the "SelectedValuePath" to be the binding path of the property that determines you're selected value

Comment: Thanks, Neel quick question, I am currently adding treeview items manually to my tree not objects. What should be my selectedvaluepath?

Comment: @arcbound08 - Normally, i would check this out first, but I'm on my way to work now.   I would guess that since the items should be TreeViewItems, you may be able to use a property of a TreeViewItem, such as the "Header" or "Name" as the selected value path.  I'm not sure on this one, but I would give it a try.

Comment: @arcbound08 - Did it work or did you find a solution ( i would like to confirm in the event that I encounter such a a situation :) )

Comment: instead of creating TreeViewItems, I created an object to bind my data to the treeview and set the selectedvaluepath to the property, cause I would also need it with a GridView and Scroller :) But if I stayed with the TreeViewItem the problem was that the style for my selected inactive item doesn't highlight it :)

Comment: Ahhh, okay, makes sense.  Just wanted to know.